# `Go is a concurrent lang` What does this mean?

Tags: concurrency, go

`Go is a concurrent lang` What does this mean?

doesn't this mean that it is a C/C++/Java.. alternative?

Answer (score 7):

A [concurrent language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_programming_language#Concurrent_programming_languages) is a language that has language constructs for concurrency.

[Go is a concurrent language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29#Concurrency) because it has "goroutines".

> #### Concurrency
>
> Go provides goroutines, small lightweight threads; the name alludes to coroutines. Goroutines are created with the go statement from anonymous or named functions.
>
> Goroutines are executed in parallel with other goroutines, including their caller. They do not necessarily run in separate threads, but a group of goroutines are multiplexed onto multiple threads — execution control is moved between them by blocking them when sending or receiving messages over channels.

Answer (score 4):

It means that it is a language with features suitable for concurrent (parallel, multithreaded, etc) programming. It has special languge constructs to support this type of programming. Concurrent programming can be done in other languages (C/C++, Java, etc) but it will (arguably) be harder and will probably result in more errors in the programs.

Comment: I like this statement: `It has special languge constructs to support this type of programming`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources about concurrent programming from some of the principal authors of the Go programming language.

[Introduction to Concurrent Programming](http://herpolhode.com/rob/lec1.pdf)

[Resources about threaded programming in the Bell Labs CSP style](http://swtch.com/~rsc/thread/)